# How to get multiple rows from a subquery in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

1.How a subquery return multiple rows in oracle db. Currently i am getting error - single-row subquery returns more than one row for the below query

```
SELECT TXN_NO,(SELECT AMT FROM TABLE1 WHERE ACC_NO='222') AS AMT FROM TABLE1
```

2. Output be like this

TXN_NO | AMOUNT

```
100    | 2500

100    | 3000
```

Comment: Please include some meaningful sample data and the expected output.  By "meaningful" I mean several different `TXN_NO` groups of records, with several different amounts.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to select all records and show their TXN_NO, but only show their AMT when their ACC_NO is 222? Or what else? Please elaborate and do as Tim suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery can return multiple rows, say, using MULTISET, but this task can be done simple & easy:

```
select t1.txn_no, t2.amt
from table1 t1, table1 t2
where t2.acc_no = '222'
```

BTW, are you sure that cartesian join is what you really need?

Answer (score 0):

By what your expected output implies, I'm not even sure you need a subquery as you have written it.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT TXN_NO, AMT
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ACC_NO = '222'
ORDER BY TXN_NO;
```